# Python : Failed to import Visualisation module

Tags: python-2.7, visualization

I'm trying to use the implementation of Chameleon's algrorithm in Python.
https://github.com/giovannipcarvalho/PyCHAMELEON/blob/master/README.md

I have also downloads the requires modules but a modules called "visualization" give me warning message.

```
    import pandas as pd
from visualization import *
from chameleon import *

    # get a set of data points
df = pd.read_csv('/path to/two_squares.csv', delimiter=' ', header=None, names=['x', 'y'])

    # create knn graph
graph = knn_graph(df, 6, verbose=True)

    # partition graph
graph = part_graph(graph, 6, df)

    # merge clusters
while merge_best(graph, df, 1, verbose=True):
 plot_data(df)
```

The results :

```
WARNING:root:Failed to import geometry msgs in rigid_transformations.py.
WARNING:root:Failed to import ros dependencies in rigid_transforms.py
WARNING:root:autolab_core not installed as catkin package, RigidTransform ros methods will be unavailable
WARNING:root:autolab_perception is not installed as a catkin package - ROS msg conversions will not be available for image wrappers
WARNING:root:autolab_perception is not installed as a catkin package - ROS msg conversions will not be available for image wrappers

***Repl Closed***
```

I'm using Python 2.7.

If you have an idea of what cause the problem and eventually fix this.